# MySQL db export: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysql, memory, phpmyadmin, export

First off, this issue has been stated on StackOverflow many times, but not where I am seeing the error. I've read through every one to make sure this is not a duplicate. Issue is occurring when I try to export a database from phpMyAdmin so that I can import it to another server. The .sql file is saving, but the last line shows the following error message.

**Environment:**

- MediaTemple Grid Server (gs)
- Wordpress plugin with MySQL database
- Exporting using phpMyAdmin

**Error message:**

`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 22505404 bytes) in <b>.../phpMyAdmin/current/libraries/export/sql.php</b> on line <b>1255</b><br />`

**PHP settings:**

I have run the command: `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`, and `phpinfo()` shows `memory_limit: 128M`.

Everywhere that I have read, this is a PHP error. Could it have anything to do with MySQL variables?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is most definitely a PHP error, probably stemming from a setting in PhpMyAdmin.
Have you tried doing a mysqldump on the command line?

Comment: I have not. I will try that and let you know how it goes.